# Fixing Footer to Bottom 10% of the Browser using CSS or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a web page with a footer section of height 400px. Now I want the footer to be fixed to bottom 10% of the browser and only when the page is scrolled down till the end of the page, then the remaining part of the footer should be visible.

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards,

manishekhawat

Answer (score 1):

The solution would be basically to make css for two versions of the footer - one for `position:fixed;` and another one for `position:static;` where the footer would be organically in the document flow.

You would then be able to write a function to toggle between the two by listening to the [scroll event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onscroll)

Comment: Thanks o.v. for the inputs, it would be really helpful if you could please put some snippet of code to achieve this :)

Comment: @manishekhawat: sure, if you add a jsfiddle of what you have so far I'll modify it